# Template for Visual Studio "Generate Method Stub"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, code-snippets, stub

I've researched the Method Stub Generator in Visual Studio, and found that it runs a code snippet.

I've never worked with snippets before, and was wondering if it would be possible to add comments above the method generated. I've found the snippet that it uses, and had a read of it, but it is all very foreign to me. I'm hoping that instead of VS creating a stub like this:

```
    private string SetString(int p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I can get something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string SetString(int p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I realise that it will only offer a small time saving, but its also a learning curve.

Any help would be great.

P.S. I've been able to edit the 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodStub.snippet" so that when a stub is created it contains the three slashes at the beginning, but this does not invoke what ever method inserts the XML skeleton.

Does anyone have any idea how Visual Studio inserts that skeleton when you enter the three slashes?

If you are interested. To enter the three slashes, i just changed these two lines in the above file from:

```
<![CDATA[$signature$
```

to:

```
<![CDATA[///
$signature$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want quick generation of a method comment block, check out ghostdoc.

http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

A quick `ctrl + shift + d` on your method produces

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p">The p.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string SetString(int p)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Notice that it takes your method name and parameters into account when generating the summary and param text. Also, if you have an existing method comment block, add a param to the method, generate again, it doesn't modify any text that already exists, just adds your new param. Awesome.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a useful tool, but I was as much hoping to learn about how the snippets work and how the auto generated comments happen as I was looking for a solution to my problem.